# CSS Calc function not fixing height property

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to develop a chat plugin and I face a problem when it comes to display the messages. Here it is: (some parts needed to be hidden because it is a highly confidential project)

[Calm before the storm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzs2G.png)

[What the >:((](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDHfQ.png)

```
<div id="tab-conversation">
   <div id="conversation-container"></div>
   <div id="input-container"></div>
</div>

$inputContainerHeight: 70px;

#tab-conversation {
  height: 100%;
}

#conversation-container {
  height: -moz-calc(100% - #{$inputContainerHeight});
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - #{$inputContainerHeight});
  height: calc(100% - #{$inputContainerHeight});
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

#input-container {
  height: $inputContainerHeight;
}
```

When messages are displayed in the `conversation-container`, the `input-container` is pushed out of the window because the `conversation-container` is a kiddo and does't want to stick to its height. Even with using the `max-height` property it dosn't work. But when I replace the `calc` function with a fixed height, the height is fixed. What do I miss ?

EDIT: I'm using scss

Comment: First, you need a preprocessor (like sass or less) to use variables like `$inputContainerHeight`

Comment: Then what is this strange syntax `#{$inputContainerHeight}`

Comment: I'm using sccs and the `#{$inputContainerHeight}` syntax is required to interpolate the value. Without it I would obtain `height: calc(100% - $inputContainerHeight);`

Comment: OK then may you add the scss tag to your question?

Comment: BTW Firefox now supports the unprefixed `calc`

Comment: _“What do I miss ?”_ – probably the usual: That a height in percent needs a parent element with an explicit height to begin with ...

Comment: I’d suggest you do yourself a favor, and implement this using flexbox ...

Comment: I first implemented it with flex box but same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as suggested by @CBroe I did myself a favor and turned every components into `flex` box where I defined the `height` property. At the end of the process I was still facing the same problem on firefox but then I found the missing ingredient in that post: [Why doesn't flex item shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-doesnt-flex-item-shrink-past-content-size). The hack is to define `min-height: 0;` (or `min-width` if the flex direction is horizontal).

To answer the initial question, a harsh but deserved comment from @CBroe:

> a height in percent needs a parent element with an explicit height to begin with

Issue closed, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

are you using scss or css?

cause you cant use `$inputContainerHeight: 70px;` in css. you can use that in scss.